# Can I ask a question about accepting payments online?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to ask a question about e-commerce payment gateways and such, on this site?

I want to accept credit cards on my site, without users having to create an account with 3rd parties such as a paypal account. I'd like to ask:

1. If there are any comparison sites,
2. What companies offer payment solutions that do not have monthly contract fees, and preferably no start-up fees (i.e. that just charge transaction fees)

Are the above two questions off topic for this site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those questions would be off-topic because they ask for a recommendation a tool, library or favorite off-site resource.  That type of question is considered to be off-topic for Pro Webmasters as it tends to attract opinionated answers and spam.

So you can't use this site to get a list of payment gateways that will work for you.

You could ask questions such as: "How do I evaluate which payment gateway would work for me?"  That question doesn't ask for off-site recommendations, but rather asks what methodology you would use to find one yourself.